# How to auto-forward email from Hotmail?

Tags: gmail, outlook.com

Some time ago -back in about 2006 (I was a late adopter)- I switched my primary email account from Hotmail to Gmail. I don't want to delete the account, if only for the remaining web-services and newsletters that are sent there, not to mention my occasional IM use.

Is there any way<sup>1</sup> automatically to forward filtered emails from Hotmail to Gmail (or any other service)?

---

1. There wasn't back in 2006, and I don't recall subsequently finding any means to do so without the use of third-party tools.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One solution would be to setup Gmail to read your email using POP3 and filtering the messages in Gmail. An additional benefit you get from this method is that it will login on your behalf so that your hotmail account won't become deactivated due to you not logging on.

To configure Gmail, use [these instructions](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=21289).

This is the configuration for Hotmail:

- Incoming Server: pop3.live.com
- Incoming Port: 995
- SSL Encryption: yes
- Outgoing Server: smtp.live.com
- Outgoing port: 25 (use port 587 if the default port is not working)
- Authentication: yes
- TLS Or SSL: yes

Comment: This is exactly what I do. It stops the 60 day deactivation timeout.

Comment: I suspect this is the better option (this way I don't have to remember to log in at all, and I can easily go 60+ days without touching a Windows Live service). Would you be able to provide an idiot's guide (as much for later-Googlers finding the question/answer as for myself)?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find a way to forward *filtered* emails from Hotmail to other services, but it is possible to forward *all* emails from Hotmail to another address.

Go to your options from the top right corner of your Hotmail inbox and click More Options.

[image]

Under "Manage Your Account," click "Forward mail to another e-mail account."  From there you can select any address you'd like to forward to.

This solution has two caveats:

1. The mail is deleted from your hotmail account after being forwarded.
2. You must log into your account once every 270 days or else it will be deactivated.  (Considering the fact that you use other services through Windows Live, this should not be a problem.)

Comment: +1 for the time taken to screen-shot, and the dedication =) As per my comment to @eagle I think I prefer the gmail pop3 option, since I can easily go 60+ days without touching Windows Live, and that solution handles the regular sign-in for me so I don't have to remember to set the calendar, or whatever.